# Swift 2 - Protocol Delegate between two UICollectionViewControllers

Tags: ios, delegates, swift2, uicollectionview, protocols

I am trying to create a protocol delegate between two `UICollectionViewController`. with the code I have I don't get any errors or warnings however, I cannot get the delegate to work. What am I missing?

Second Collection View

```
    public protocol LettersCollectionViewDelegate: class {

        func DidSelectLetter(collectioView: UICollectionView,letter: Character, resultString:String)

    }

    class LettersCollectionView: UICollectionViewController {

        // DELEGATE
        weak var delegate: LettersCollectionViewDelegate?

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! LetterCellView



           delegate?.DidSelectLetter(collectionView, letter: "T", resultString:"TestString")

    }

}
```

First Collection View

```
class AnswerCollectionView: UICollectionViewController {

   let lettersView = LettersCollectionView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.lettersView.delegate = self

    }

}

extension AnswerCollectionView: LettersCollectionViewDelegate {

    func DidSelectLetter(collectioView: UICollectionView, letter: Character, resultString: String) {

        print(letter)
    }
}
```

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: You are creating a new instance of LettersCollectionView in AnsweracollectionView and setting the delegate on that instance. This won't be the instance that is on screen. What is the relationship between these two view controllers?  Does one present the other via segue? Are they both on screen via container view controllers?

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried to add the delegate to my main ViewController but still not get the delegate to work

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the two view controllers?  Are you using container views in your main view controller?  Why did you use two uicollectionview rather than two uicollectionview controllers?

Comment: The two `UICollectionViewControllers` are created in the storyboard and loaded in the view controller. I am doing this so I can have two collection view controllers in one view controller

Comment: I have added an image to explain it better

Comment: You don't need to use container views to do that. You simply need to check which collectionview is passed to the delegate method and handle it appropriately, but since you are using containers you need to get the reference to the first collectionviewcontroller and set it as the delegate on the second collection viewcontroller. You can do this in `prepareForSegue` by getting the destination view controllers from each of the embed segues

Comment: Thank you .. I haven't quite understood that.. Is there an example I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your delegate to be the instance of the `AnswerCollectionView` that is embedded in your root view controller. Similarly, you need to set the delegate on the `LettersCollectionView` instance that is in the root view.  `let lettersView = LettersCollectionView()` creates a *new instance*.

You can get the required references in `prepareForSegue` in your root view controller. You need to give the two embded segues in your storyboard identifiers, so you can identify them.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var lettersView: LettersCollectionView?
   var answersView: AnswersCollectionView?

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "lettersSegue" {
           let lettersView = segue.destinationViewController as? LettersCollectionView
       } else if segue.identifier = "answersSegue" {
           let answersView = segue.destinationViewController as? AnswersCollectionView
       }

       self.lettersView?.delegate = self.answersView
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your example. Now I am trying to follow your advice of adding the collection views without using container. Maybe is going to be easier to communicate between the two if they are initialised inside the view controller. I am going to accept your answer for the big help I got from you. Thank you very much again. Going to try your code as well.